# Talend: Create table if does not exist, update it if not does not work

Tags: mysql, talend

I want to create a job in Talend Open Studio where I can insert data if data does not already exist and update rows if the row already exists.

I tried to use a tMap with two outputs:

1. output1 : fill data into a tMysqlOutput with :

   - action on table : default (no operation is carried out)
   - action on data : insert
2. output2 : update data using another tMysqlOutput with :

   - action on table : default (no operation is carried out)
   - action on data : update

But I want it to update only the modified rows.
How can I do that?

**EDITED :**
The following table is an example that could explain more my problem.
[image]

I want the following result :

- if the name changed so I have the current date in the "updated_on" field
- if the name does not change (there is no modified data) the "updated_on" field does not change

Comment: Why you dont use action on data: Insert or update?

Comment: I used it but that updates all the data and not only the modified rows

Comment: can you determine somehow which records are "modified"?

Comment: In fact, I want to update only the rows that have some changed data

Comment: @xto I edited the post

Comment: can you share your job ?

Comment: May be this is useful : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: so, table with `updated_on` column is your source table? simplest way is to get max updated_on from target table and get records from source table where updated_on > max_updated_on